# Upgrading from Fedora 23 to Fedora 24 without updating the font

Tags: fedora, gnome, upgrade, fonts

Fedora 24 includes an [update of its default font Cantarell](https://fedoramagazine.org/font-improvements-fedora-24-workstation/) but I prefer the old version:

[image]

How can I upgrade from Fedora 23 to 24 and keep the old font (or at least configure font rendering such that the font doesn't look as thin and narrow as in the screenshot above)?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 23, 24.

Excluding a package from install or update :

Add a line to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` ( Previously `/etc/yum.conf` )

```
exclude=package-name*
```

Example http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-centos-linux-yum-update-exclude-packages/

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The package *abattis-cantarell-fonts* was installed, so I added it to the exclude list. After the upgrade to 24, this package is no longer installed at all but I have the new font.